# External Identity server authorizing own resource

Tags: oauth-2.0

My company is being requested to use an external identity server (our client) to authorize an api that we are responsible for and host. IE, we have a backoffice piece of software we have built that a client logs into and uses (vpn) hosted in our own infrastructure. We have our own webfarm that exposes API access to certain functions over this backoffice software. A third party (a client of our client) is building a website that utilises our API. We've been requested to use the client credential flow between website and api. Ordinarily we would expect the identity and authorisation of our own api to sit inside our own infrastructure for which we are responsible for. IE one identity service for many of our own apis. Is this normal to have our api resource authorized outside of our own infrastructure? Is this a security concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any other third party needs to call your API this would not work. Also your API SLAs are now across 2 companies - which is not good.

A more standard and extensible option would be to get the partner back end to call your own OAuth token endpoint, within an Authorization Server you are responsible for.

Their code would be precisely the same - but the partner would use a different URL to get tokens.

These days most companies use a low cost and highly available cloud provider as the Authorization Server - such as AWS - rather than hosting this type of component on premise.

Happy to answer any follow up questions ..

Comment: Thanks. It does strike me as odd with the auth off prem. (However, oauth is delegated auth anyway?) They are using Okta as an auth server? Which, I think, is like identity server? I assumed the resource and token server should be on the same backbone. Currently, we host everything for the client. Their partner (external website) would just call our oauth token endpoint and attach the bearer to the api request. Ceding out authorisation to the client would create triangular dependencies and I’d lose control of the access. How does AWS help? I assume the api resource sits inside AWS with it?

Comment: Yep - agree with you - the client should get a token from your token endpoint rather than their own token endpoint. Typically your own token endpoint should not be part of your actual API - it should be part of your Authorization Server (could be Okta, AWS etc). Your API and auth server don't have to be hosted together.